# What happened to the sort order of tags in the user profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, my-tags

Is there a valid reason why the user profile page has changed so that the tags are now sorted by number of posts in ascending order instead of descending?

Comment: It's not sorted in ascending order of number of posts.  It's sorted in ascending order of tag length (eg c# = 2, sqlite = 6)!

Comment: Oh, I see that now.  Wow, that's not the most useful metric :-)

Comment: And the number in **x n** is the tag length (just to state the obvious).

Comment: Wow, interesting to see how many posts that I've participated in that have ridiculous tags.  `[id]`, `[web]`, `[set]` and `[value]`, for instance.

Comment: The actual numbers with the tags are completely bogus too.  This is borked.

Comment: @Hans - see my earlier comment

Comment: when is the fix supposed to be put?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed.