# Tags showing in reverse frequency order?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the sort order of tags in the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61804/what-happened-to-the-sort-order-of-tags-in-the-user-profile)

[image]

Comment: I also have the same problem

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61804/what-happened-to-the-sort-order-of-tags-in-the-user-profile

Comment: Not reverse frequency, but on length of tag with **x n** showing the length of the tag.